# Update modified rows in Excel to SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, vsto

I have a MS Excel vsto application where I receive data from a SQL Server table. The user can modify the data in the sheet and with an Change event

```
worksheet.Change += new XlsInterop.Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler(ColRangeSelChange);
```

the changed cell is directly updated in the SQL Server table.

Now, the user first wants to review his changes before it is all saved to the database. So I want to add a 'Save' button and when the user hits the button, all changed cells / rows are updated in the database. Because the Excel sheet contains about 15000 records, I only want to update the changed rows.

Comment: You should provide code for what you have already done. We are not going to make code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add flag on a column to the lines, change this flag to true when the line have changed.

When you use the save button, loop on the lines and update only the lines with the flag = true